# Android-Butterknife: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Required view xxx was not found

Tags: android, butterknife

Android Studio 3.1,
Gradle 4.1,
Java 1.8,
Android 6.0,
ButterКnife 8.8.1

I try to use ButterKnife on android app. But I have a problem.

in **build.gradle**:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
```

in **app/build.gradle**:

```
implementation "com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1"
kapt "com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1"
```

Here my xml layout: **offer_details_pdf.xml**

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/offerDetailsToolBarMainContainer"
        layout="@layout/offer_details_top_container"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/noItemsTextView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/no_items"
        android:visibility="gone"/>  

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

In my activity

```
public class OfferDetailsPdfActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MyInterface {
    @BindView(R.id.offerDetailsToolBarMainContainer)
    ConstraintLayout offerDetailsToolBarMainContainer;
    @BindView(R.id.noItemsTextView)
    TextView noItemsTextView;    

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    setContentView(R.layout.offer_details_pdf);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
}        

// implment method of interface MyInterface
@Override
public void showTopAndBottomContainer() {
   offerDetailsToolBarMainContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

// implment method of interface MyInterface
@Override
public void showNoItems() {
  noItemsTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Method `showTopAndBottomContainer()` success work. But method `showNoItems()` not.
I get error:

```
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myproject.android.customer.debug/com.myproject.android.customer.ui.OfferDetailsPdfActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Required view 'noItemsTextView' with ID 2131296554 for field 'noItemsTextView' was not found. If this view is optional add '@Nullable' (fields) or '@Optional' (methods) annotation.
    android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
    android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Required view 'noItemsTextView' with ID 2131296554 for field 'noItemsTextView' was not found. If this view is optional add '@Nullable' (fields) or '@Optional' (methods) annotation.
com.myproject.android.customer.ui.OfferDetailsPdfActivity_ViewBinding.<init>(OfferDetailsPdfActivity_ViewBinding.java:73)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
            at butterknife.ButterKnife.createBinding(ButterKnife.java:199)
            at butterknife.ButterKnife.bind(ButterKnife.java:124)
```

Why it's not working?

Comment: Why do you have and `@Override` above `showNoItems()` method? Also do you have in gradle: `annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'`

Comment: I update my post

Comment: @Yupi the @ override most likely comes from the MyInterface interface.

Comment: yes, showNoItems() is implement of interface MyInterface

Comment: @Alexei try to downgrade `ButterKnife` on version: `8.4.0` in: `annotationProcessor`, `library` and `plugin`

Comment: 8.4.0 - Not help. Same error

Comment: Try using `@Nullable` or `@Optional` where you are binding the view.

Comment: @Alexei If that helps I'll add it as an answer.

Comment: If I set @Nullable on variable "noItemsTextView" than get another error: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference

Comment: If I set @Optional on method showNoItems() than I get old error:  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Required view 'noItemsTextView' with ID 2131296554 for field 'noItemsTextView' was not found. If this view is optional add '@Nullable' (fields) or '@Optional' (methods) annotation.

Comment: You have to use the annotations on the fields not on any method. And I cannot find `R.id.noItemsTextView` in the XML. :/

Comment: Yes, the problem was in id in xml .After set id = noItemsTextView then error is gone. Thanks

Comment: I should add that as an answer so it might help somebody. Please accept the answer. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no text view matching with id `R.id.noItemsTextView` in the XML.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem and battled with it for a full day
my ids where fine my code was right too coz i tripple checked it for a whole day
then i found some thing i never imagined was the root cause

```
ButterKnife.bind(this);
setContentView(layoutID());
```

changed to

```
setContentView(layoutID());
ButterKnife.bind(this);
```

The problem was gone

Answer (score 0):

You might have forgotten to apply the ButterKnife plugin. Go to your build.gradle file and **below** `apply plugin: 'com.android.library'` add this: `apply plugin: 'com.jakewharton.butterknife'`

Comment: I get error: Plugin with id 'com.jakewharton.butterknife' not found.

Comment: Honestly it's best to read the installation guide on GitHub. You also need to include `classpath 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-gradle-plugin:8.8.1'` in your BuildScript. https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife#library-projects

Comment: Unable to find method 'com.android.build.gradle.api.BaseVariant.getOutputs()Ljava/util/List;'.
Possible causes for this unexpected error include:<ul><li>Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)

Comment: Google not help.